# What is the "joy" that was set before Jesus mentioned in Hebrews 12:2

Tags: word-study, hebrews, new-testament

> [Hebrews 12:2](https://biblehub.com/hebrews/12-2.htm)
>
> looking to Jesus, the founder and perfecter of our faith, who for
>   **the joy that was set before him** endured the cross, despising the shame, and is seated at the right hand of the throne of God.

What is the **joy** that was set before Jesus mentioned in the verse above?

Answer (score 0):

There are few texts of scripture that so clearly set out the sacrifice of Jesus so clearly than by contrasting what Jesus wanted to achieve vs the pain of execution.  The joy set before Jesus was his goal in redeeming the human race for no other reason than love (1 John 4:8, 16).  Ellicott summarises this well:

> Who for the joy that was set before him endured the cross.--The
>   literal meaning is very forcible, endured a cross, despising shame;
>   the shame of such a death being set over against the joy that lay
>   before Him. Here again we have the thought of Hebrews 2:9 (Philippians
>   2:9-10); the joy of His accomplished purpose (Isaiah 53:11; Matthew
>   25:21; Luke 10:21-22) and the glory with which He was crowned (John
>   17:1; 1Peter 1:11) being the reward for His "obedience even unto
>   death." The whole form of the expression (comp. especially Hebrews
>   6:18, "the hope set before us") shows that Jesus is presented to us as
>   an example not of endurance only, but also of faith (Hebrews 2:12).

Thus, Jesus not only accomplished His purpose to save humanity but also set an example (1 Peter 2:21; John 13:15, Eph 4:32, 5:1; Col 3:1-3) that we are instructed to fix our attention to (Heb 12:2, 3) and thus have the mind of Christ (1 Cor 2:16).  See also Meyers NY commentary on this verse.

Answer (score 0):

Peace - as in "the punishment that brought us peace" (Isaiah 53:5). He is only requoting Isaiah 53.

"...looking to Jesus, the founder and perfecter of our faith, who, for the "punishment that brought us peace" that was set before him, endured the cross, despising the shame, and is seated at the right hand of the throne of God". Hebrews 12:2.

I hope this helps.